# MediaWiki: Dynamic Templates (infobox)

Tags: php, dynamic, mediawiki

I'm sure this works for infoboxes and pretty much anything else in MediaWiki, however, my issue is that I have a template that uses Semantic Forms.  The forms also populate an infobox.  One of the drop down menus are pulled in from Categories.  So I have "Cat 1", "Cat 2", and "Cat 3".  So, now I have 1000 pages in MW and on 500 of them I need to rename "Cat 2" to "Category 2".  How would I be able to "mass edit" all 500 pages to reflect this change?  I'm wanting to do it dynamically, so that I don't have to manually change 500 pages.  Is there a way to do this?  If not now, is there a way to fix this for future happenings so that I don't make this mistake again?

Any feedback is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you assign 'Cat 2' to those pages ?

If you used Semantic Form, you may have created a 'Cat 2 form' and a corresponding 'Cat 2 template' where you assigned the category to the resulting page.

In this case, all you have to do is update the 'Cat 2 template' to reflect the new category and all pages using that template will be refreshed by a background job.

If you have assigned the category to these pages manually :

1- Use the [MediaWiki ReplaceText extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aReplace_Text) to search and replace the category assignments
2- Use a template for you category assignments - that will save you a lot of time the next time you have to change categories.